# Get Segmentation Fault (Core Dumped) error in Named Pipes

Tags: python, c++, segmentation-fault, named-pipes, coredump

Trying to implement reverse string using named pipes in C++ & python on Ubuntu, I get Segmentation Fault (Core Dumped) error when I try to take user-input. Program works flawlessly when the string is pre-defined.

Following is the writer program in C++ that writes into file:

```
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <string>
#include <string.h>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    int fd;
    char *myfifo = "/home/Desktop/myFile";

    /* create the FIFO (named pipe) */
    mkfifo(myfifo, 0666);

    /* write message to the FIFO */
    fd = open(myfifo, O_WRONLY);
    char const*msg;
    cout << "Please enter string to be reversed: ";
    cin>>msg;

   // msg="This is the string to be reversed";
   // The above line works fine which is pre-defined string.

    write(fd, msg, strlen(msg)+1);
    close(fd);

    /* remove the FIFO */
    unlink(myfifo);

    return 0;
}
```

Following is my Reader program in Python:

```
import os
import sys

path= "/home/Desktop/myFile"

fifo=open(path,'r')
str=fifo.read()
revstr=str[::-1]
print(revstr)
fifo.close()
```

After executing above files simultaneously, I get following output respectively:

Writer.cpp =>

```
Please enter string to be reversed: qwerty
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

Reader.py => `No Output, Blank`

After googling, I found this means Trying to access read-only part of memory.

But, how do I remove this error in order to get string from user? Do I need to change file permissions, to make it write while reading? What could possibly work?

Comment: `msg` has no *memory* associated with it. Use a `std::string` for an easy life?

Comment: You have a pointer `msg`, but you never make it point anywhere.

Comment: For future reference, your output shows a core file was generated. Learning to load these in your debugger and see for yourself what happened is an invaluable skill to practice (admittedly in this case there will probably be lots of noise from the basic_istream templates, but it's worth taking a look).

Answer (score 2):

[This](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/operator_gtgt2) documents the `operator>>` overload you're currently using:

```
template<class CharT, class Traits>
basic_istream<CharT,Traits>& operator>>(basic_istream<CharT,Traits>& st, CharT* s);
```

which in reality means roughly

```
basic_istream<char>& operator>>(basic_istream<char>& st, char* s);
```

(where you call it with `st = cin` and `s = msg`).

The documentation says this overload

> ... extracts successive characters and stores them at successive locations of a character array whose first element is pointed to by s

but `s` (or `msg`) doesn't point to an array where you can store those characters. It's uninitialized, and storing anything in there without initializing it to point at some valid location is **Undefined Behaviour**.

This overload is not recommended anyway, because you can't use it safely. You don't know in advance how many bytes will be read, which means you can't choose a safe size for the array to store them in.

Using the [`std::string` overload](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/operator_ltltgtgt) instead allows the string class to take care of storing however many bytes are read, because `std::string` (unlike a plain array) can grow itself as required.